# Find differences between two arrays of objects where the comparison is upon the return value of a method call

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, object, array-difference

I have got a problem with PHP function `array_diff()`.

In both cases I'm using it on arrays of the same class objects.

First case:

```
public function findFreeUsers($weekId)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $week = $em->getRepository(Week::class)->findOneBy(["id" => $weekId]);
    $busyWeeks = $em->getRepository(Week::class)->findWeekBetweenDates($week);
    $busyUsers = array();
    foreach ($busyWeeks AS $busyWeek) {
        $tmp = $em->getRepository(UserWeek::class)->findBy(["week" => $busyWeek["id"]]);
        if ($tmp != null) {
            foreach($tmp AS $singleWeek) {
                $busyUsers[] = $singleWeek->getUser();
            }
        }
    }
    $allUsers = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();
    $freeUsers = array_diff($allUsers, $busyUsers);
    return $freeUsers;
}
```

Second case:

```
public function findFreeCars($weekId)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $week = $em->getRepository(Week::class)->findOneBy(["id" => $weekId]);
    $busyWeeks = $em->getRepository(Week::class)->findWeekBetweenDates($week);
    $busyCars = array();
    foreach ($busyWeeks AS $busyWeek) {
        $tmp = $em->getRepository(CarWeek::class)->findBy(["week" => $busyWeek["id"]]);
        if ($tmp != null) {
            foreach($tmp AS $singleWeek) {
                $busyCars[] = $singleWeek->getCar();
            }
        }
    }
    $allCars = $em->getRepository(Car::class)->findAll();
    $freeCars = array_diff($allCars, $busyCars);
    return $freeCars;
}
```

I'm dumping these arrays and all of them are arrays with objects of the same class.

In first case it works, in second I've got:

> Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Car could not be converted to string

Comment: Can you please give a sample response of both arrays ?

Comment: Please read here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#refsect1-function.array-diff-notes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use array_diff to compare the arrays with objects.

To do it properly you need to use [array_udiff()](http://php.net/array_udiff) and you need to define what "difference" between objects means.

For example objects may be different if they have different id

```
function compareCars(Car $objA, Car $objB) {
  return $objA->getId() <=> $objB->getId();
}

$diff = array_udiff($allCars, $busyCars, 'compareCars')
```

If you added for example ComparableInterface to every class that you want to compare via id with just one method getId() then you could use the benefits of polymorphism

```
interface ComparableInterface
{
   public function getId();
}


class Car implements ComparableInterface
{
    public function getId()
    {
       return $this->id;
    }
    //rest of the class source 
}

function compareCars(ComparableInterface $objA, ComparableInterface $objB) {
   return $objA->getId() <=> $objB->getId();
}
```

or even define compare() method that returns for every object if it's equal or not

```
interface AdvancedComparableInterface extends ComparableInterface
{
   public function compare(ComparableInterface $obj);
}

class Car implements AdvancedComparableInterface
{
    public function getId()
    {
       return $this->id;
    }

    public function compare(ComparableInterface $obj)
    {
       return $this->getId() <=> $obj->getId();
    }
    //rest of the class source 
}

function compareCars(AdvancedComparableInterface $objA, ComparableInterface $objB) {
   return $objA->compare($objB);
}
```

As you see you can use multiple ways of defining if the object is the same as the other one. For example the cars you could be compared by VIN

**Side note:**

Executing the queries in a loop is a bad idea in terms of doctrine's performance. It's be better if you make one query by passing ids of busyWeek as array to findBy method.

Comment: To use this approach with arbitrary objects (without `getId()` method or its equivalent), comparison callback can be implemented like this: `$callback = fn (object $x, object $y): int => spl_object_id($x) <=> spl_object_id($y);`